# Is this transistor amplifier with low pass filter correct? How should I measure the gain and frequency range?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, gain, low-pass, bandwidth

[image]

My goal is a gain of 100-130 and a frequency range of 1-10 kHz.

Comment: Read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/685329/330261).

Comment: Have you simulated your circuit to see how it performs?

Comment: In a comment to @periblepsis , you've given some important amplifier specifications that affect any engineering design approach. These should be added to your top-level question, along with stated specs of gain=100-130, frequency span 1-10 kHz. BTW; is that *1 Hz* to *10kHz* or is it *1kHz to 10 kHz* ? Does gain=100-300 refer to *voltage gain* or to *power gain*?

Comment: it is 1kHz to 10kHz and the gain of 100 - 130 refers to the voltage gain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Intro

Your approach shows at least one serious misunderstanding about how AC gain works in BJT CE amplifier stages. You've AC-grounded all three stages. This means *insane* voltage gains and *insane* distortion, as well. The AC-gain for each stage varies as the applied signal varies. This guarantees distortion by the time the last stage is reached, if not well before then.

Of course, it also guarantees a temperature-dependent AC gain.

Finally, an AC voltage gain nothing near to what you want.

Simply put, the whole thing is a **fail**.

### Goals and Decisions

The specs appear to be:

- *"gain of 100-130 and a frequency range of 1-10 kHz"*: I'll take this to mean \$100\le A_v\le 130\$ is fine and that it must cover *at least* the frequency range of \$1\:\text{kHz}\le f\le 10\:\text{kHz}\$, but that a wider range is also fine.
- *"Minumum at Supply voltage of 12 V"*: I'll take this to mean that you want \$V_{_\text{CC}}\ge 12\:\text{V}\$. This is fine.
- *"a Load resistance of 1k"*: So \$R_{_\text{L}}=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Got it.
- *"Output swing 6V pk-pk"*: This suggests that the input will be 100 to 130 times less. Let's call it \$50\:\text{mV}_\text{PP}\$ and set \$A_v=120\$ as the goal.
- *"Max input current of 10 uA"*: This suggests an input impedance of \$\frac{25\:\text{mV}_\text{PK}}{10\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 2.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

You will need global NFB. Just as I wrote.

You do ***not*** need three stages. Two would be enough.

Since you seem more comfortable DC biasing standard CE BJT stages, let's stay with that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpWf2y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 1st stage splits up the DC biasing emitter resistance into two parts. We need something that the NFB can work into and this provides it. So we'll AC bypass just part of the 1st stage's DC biasing emitter resistance, but AC bypass *all* of the 2nd stage's DC biasing emitter resistance so as to get the maximum AC gain available in the 2nd stage. We'll then arrange the NFB to throw away some of that available gain to set \$A_v=120\$ and at the same time also deal with BJT vagaries, operating temperature variations, and so on.

The power supply rail isn't decided just yet as it is flexible to the need.

Also, there's no THD specification here, either. This impacts the selected collector currents. But I'm deferring this. We'll look at it when we get to the end and see if it is acceptable.

### 2nd Stage

I never want to allow the BJT's \$V_{_\text{CE}}\$ to get lower than about \$2\:\text{V}\$ if the specifications for the power supply rail permit. And yours do permit. So that's the minimum. Given the \$6\:\text{V}_\text{PP}\$ required output, this means we need to support at least \$V_{_\text{CE}}=8\:\text{V}\$ and that the quiescent \$V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{Q}}}=5\:\text{V}\$.

I'd also like to ensure that \$V_{_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}}\ge 1\:\text{V}\$, if at all possible. (DC bias stability over temperature.) More is better. Twice that would be perfect. Let's just pick a number, \$V_{_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}}= 1.2\:\text{V}\$.

This means that \$V_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}= 6.2\:\text{V}\$ and that means, I think, we can stay with \$V_{_\text{CC}}= 12\:\text{V}\$ (though higher would be nicer because it keeps the variations in collector current within a narrower operating range.)

The quiescent collector current is an issue. You are driving \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Broadly speaking, this suggests a collector resistor that's a bit smaller and that means a pretty high quiescent collector current.

Looking at the [OnSemi 2N3904 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n3903-d.pdf), I see that they appear to be okay with a collector current around \$10\:\text{mA}\$. And a quick check on dissipation and the thermal resistance of the package, I find that this number may be okay for use in open-air. So let's go with that figure for the 2nd stage: \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}= 10\:\text{mA}\$. (\$r_e^{\:'}\approx 2.5\:\Omega\$.)

This means the collector resistor is \$\frac{12\:\text{V}-6.2\:\text{V}}{10\:\text{mA}}=580\:\Omega\$. We'll set that to \$R_{_\text{C}}=560\:\Omega\$ and call it good. This suggests, without taking attenuation into account, that the 2nd stage \$A_v=\frac{560\:\Omega}{2.5\:\Omega+200\:\text{m}\Omega}\approx 207\$. (The \$200\:\text{m}\Omega\$ is added in here because I do that to account for bulk emitter resistance, which is always also present. There are also other parasitics, such as the base bulk resistance which is on the order of a few dozen Ohms.) But loaded with \$R_{_\text{L}}\$, more like \$A_v\approx 133\$.

This also means the emitter resistor is \$\frac{1.2\:\text{V}}{10\:\text{mA}}=120\:\Omega\$. We'll set that to \$R_{_\text{E}}=120\:\Omega\$ and call it good, too.

From the datasheet, it appears that \$V_{_\text{BE}}\approx 750\:\text{mV}\$ at this current. But let's plan for \$V_{_\text{BE}}= 800\:\text{mV}\$. This means \$V_{_{\text{B}_\text{Q}}}= 2.0\:\text{V}\$. I also plan to use \$\beta=100\$ as a design value. There are arguments for using less, no question. But I want to keep this simple as we go.

Now, using the rule of 10 for the biasing pair, I find that the grounded resistor will be \$\frac{2\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{mA}}=2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. (Luckily, this is the 2nd stage and not the 1st, or else we'd have exceeded the input source's current compliance specification of \$10\:\mu\text{A}\$.) I also find that the other biasing resistor will be \$\frac{12\:\text{V}-2\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{mA}+100\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 9.1\:\text{k}\Omega\$. That's a standard value, too.

So the circuit is looking something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMvJGk.png)</sup>

### 1st Stage

The 2nd stage will load down the 1st stage, too. But let's use the fact that this load is about half that (twice the impedance) of \$R_{_\text{L}}\$ and make a design decision to use half the quiescent current for the 1st stage. We already know that if we do so, then we can meet the input current compliance requirement. We could go even lower (and accept more attenuation between the 1st and 2nd stages), but since it meets the specs there's no need here.

So for the 1st stage, set \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}= 5\:\text{mA}\$. For the 1st stage, we don't need to support the wide-ranging collector. So we can set it lower. I'm going to set \$V_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}= 4\:\text{V}\$, in round numbers. From that it would seem \$R_{_\text{C}}=1.6\:\text{k}\Omega\$. But, if anything, I'd like to lower the quiescent current a little bit so I'm going to go with \$R_{_\text{C}}=1.8\:\text{k}\Omega\$, adjusting \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}= 4.4\:\text{mA}\$. (\$r_e^{\:'}\approx 5.7\:\Omega\$.)

This means my DC biasing emitter resistance is \$R_{_\text{E}}=270\:\Omega\$. Computing the base biasing, I get something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXAT9S.png)</sup>

The gain here should be \$A_v=\frac{1800\:\Omega}{120\:\Omega+5.7\:\Omega+200\:\text{m}\Omega}\approx 14\$. But it's loaded down by perhaps around \$1.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$ on the 2nd stage, so the net should be about \$A_v=7\$, instead.

(Note also that the 1st stage's loading on the source meets the requirements.)

### NFB

Overall, I figure I get an open loop gain of about \$A_v=7\cdot 130\approx 900\$, in round numbers. Frankly, there are other parasitics and the Early Effect. The Early Effect justifies a downgrade of 10%. There's more, but without digging deeper I can only justify 10%, so let's call the open loop gain \$A_v=800\$.

This means the NFB resistance needs to be

```
solve(Eq(solve(Eq(avo/(1+avo*x),avc),x)[0],re/(x+re)),x)[0].subs({avo:800,avc:120,re:120}).n()
16821.1764705882
```

I'll round that up to \$18\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Here's the final schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdEGiU.png)</sup>

Let's pop that into LTspice:

[image]

The closed loop gain into the load works out to \$10^{^\frac{40.964}{20}}\approx 112\$. That's surprisingly close all things considered.

LTspice reports a total harmonic distortion of about 2.2%. That's probably okay for this purpose. (It's mostly because we didn't have a lot of excess open loop gain, though. We could increase the open loop gain, or decrease the closed loop gain, to bring that down a bit.)

Take note that this was ***not*** some hunt-and-peck process. I didn't hack values until the results came around. Instead I followed a specific process that took me from start to finish, using the rule of 10 to avoid getting mired in too much equation detail where possible, and arrived very close to the intended destination.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149512/discussion-on-answer-by-periblepsis-is-this-transistor-amplifier-with-low-pass-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You have way too much gain. You appear to have added up the three gains to get a total. In fact the three gains are multiplied together to get the total gain.

I make the three gains of the three stages 29, 38 and 55 which when added give a total of 122 but when multiplied give a total gain of 60,610!

For that amount of required gain I think you would do better with just two stages, each with a partially by-passed emitter.

Comment: Yes, two stages would be sufficient as you've suggested. It seems an added unstated spec is 6v p-p across a 1k load resistor.  That will be a bit tricky for a learning designer if a 12V supply is used. To ease the design process, one might add a third stage having low voltage gain.

Comment: The supply is not limted to 12v it is only the minimum

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your preamp has way too much gain (amplification) causing severe distortion since it has no negative feedback.

I straightened some of your "wires all over the place" and cropped your schematic.

Your lowpass filter begins to cut frequencies above 300Hz and cuts 1.5kHz to -3dB. Its cutoff slope is very gradual.

Here is a simulation of the 1st transistor:
[image: transistor preamp]

[image: 1st transistor sim]

Comment: How do I lessen the gain and how does each stage affects one's gain?

Comment: You were already told to add unbypassed emitter resistors to reduce the gain and distortion of each stage. Adding Global negative feedback will also do it.